# Is there a name for the replaceable wildcard "morpheme"?

Tags: morphemes

The very rare phenomenon I'm talking about is a part of a word that indicates that the word encompasses a number of hyponyms, which are arrived at by replacing that part. It is probably easier to understand by example:

- **veg*n** (meaning "either a vegan or a vegetarian")
- **foocubus** (meaning "either a succubus or an incubus")
- **Kosov@** (meaning "either the spelling *Kosovo* or *Kosova*")
- Spanish **Chican@** (meaning "either a Chicano or a Chicana)

Is there a name for the "morpheme" (if you can call it that) *****, **foo** and **@** in the examples above? Has this phenomenon ever been the topic of an academic study?

Comment: In computer science *foo* is one of a group of words called [metasyntactic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable), which can stand for anything or be used as a wildcard more or less in the same way you're doing it here. I'm not aware of this happening in natural language with enough frequency and consistency to be studied as a phenomenon.

Comment: The asterisk symbol is called [the _Kleene closure_ or _Kleene star_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), named after the mathematician Stephen Kleene /'kli:ni:/.

Comment: Jlawler, in this context, it's not a Kleene star. A Kleene star denotes the set of all finite strings obtained using a given finite alphabet. Here the asterisk denotes something else entirely

Comment: Except the Spanish @, I haven't seen any of these really used productively—just on an ad-hoc basis. Upon seeing "veg*n" without further explanation I might also read it as "vegan, but censored" (cf "sh*t", which is very seldom used to mean "shot", "shut", etc).